# Representation of Levi subgroup $L\subset P \subset G$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a split connected reductive group over a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with split maximal torus $T$ of rank $d$ and simple roots $\Delta$. Furthermore associated to $I\subset \Delta$ a standard parabolic $P:=P_I \subset G$ with Levi decomposition $P=LU$ which contains $T$.

Is it then true that every finite-dimensional algebraic representation $V$ of $L$ is induced by an element $\lambda \in X^*(T)\cong \mathbb{Z}^d$ or $V$ is a direct sum of irreducible $L$-representations $V_i$ which are induced by $\lambda_i \in X^*(T)\cong \mathbb{Z}^d$?

Comment: What do you mean by "finite-dimensional algebraic representation $V$ of $L$ is induced by an element $\lambda \in X^*(T)$" ?

Comment: As $L$ is semi-simple it is especially reductive. Hence $V$ complete reducible i.e. $V$ is a direct sum of simple $L$-representations (Milne, Algebraic Groups: The Theory of Group Schemes of Finite Type over a Field, Theorem 22.42.) Again $L$ is reductive, hence all simple modules are classified by dominant integral weights $\lambda \in X^*(T)$ (Jantzen, Representation of Algebraic Group, Part II, Corollary 2.7). Any doubts?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi I had an vague idea that you can construct from some $\lambda \in X^*(T)$ a finite dimensional $L$ representation. Does the comment I recently wrote, answer your question?

Comment: Do you consider representations over the based field or over an algebraic closure?

Comment: Over the base field as I thought Jantzen does.

Comment: "Does the comment I recently wrote, answer your question?" Yes

Comment: Do you assume that $T$ is a split torus?

Comment: Yes. But I think the $\lambda \in X^*(T)$ should be in $\{ \mu \in X^*(T) \mid \langle \mu, \alpha^\vee{}\rangle >=0 \text{ for all } \alpha \in I\}$ rather than dominant.

Comment: So dominant weights with respect to the simple roots of L

Comment: Any representation of a connected reductive group $L$  defined over a field $k$ of characteristic 0 is a direct sum of irreducible representations. If $k$ is algebraically closed, then any irreducible representation of $L$ is a representation with highest weight  (what you call "induced by $\lambda$"), and I think that the same holds over any field $k$ of characteristic 0 assuming that $L$ is split (that is, contains a split maximal torus).

Comment: For irreducible representations of not necessarily split groups over an arbitrary field see J. Tits, Représentations linéaires irréductibles d'un groupe réductif sur un corps quelconque, Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik | Volume 1971: Issue 247.

Comment: Link: [J. Tits, Représentations linéaires irréductibles d'un groupe réductif sur un corps quelconque, J. Reine Angew. Math. 247 (1971), 196–220](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002185725).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thanks for your answer. What you wrote for split reductive groups should be the same what I wrote in my comment with additional theorems. But thank you very much for the reference for non-split case!! Thats new for me.

Comment: How can I refer to comments?

Comment: Yes, [like this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372985/representation-of-levi-subgroup-l-subset-p-subset-g#comment943861_372985). Namely, you right-click on the *time of the comment* and choose "copy link address". Then you use this link address as usual.